# In assembly, How to do 5 byte multiply?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, 32-bit

I have to do 5 byte unsigned Int square. For example, I made a 5 byte random unsigned interger, and then want to know square these random unsigned interger at assembly lang.
In x86-32 and MASM assembler, They does not support over the 32bit. So I meet trouble that square of it. We can use Irvine32 library, and below pic is the Irvine32 library list.
[Irvine32 library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qjCk.png)
Please help me how to square these random 5byte unsigned interger.

Maybe, I think 5byte divide into 4 byte and 1byte to square it.
But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Same as how compilers handle `uint64_t` when compiling for 32-bit.  With 1 extra byte instead of 4, you can just zero-extend it to 32 to get a full 64-bit integer and then apply the usual methods, like `mul r32` and two `imul reg, reg` for the low x high cross products.  As in [How can I multiply two 64-bit numbers using x86 assembly language?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23588103). There are multiple other Q&As about the algorithm.